# How can I interpret an unsigned int value as a four letter word?

Tags: c++, int, ascii, unsigned, modulus

My job is to reverse the process I used in my variable int sum. However, I must use the modulus operator along with integer division. Here is my code so far.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string fourLetterWord;

    cout << setw(10) << "" << "Please enter a four letter word! ";
    while (cin >> fourLetterWord)
    {
        if (fourLetterWord.length() == 4)
        {
            cout << setw(10) << "" << "The ASCII value of " << fourLetterWord[3] << "=" << int(fourLetterWord[3]) << endl;
            cout << setw(10) << "" << "The ASCII value of " << fourLetterWord[2] << " = " << int(fourLetterWord[2]) << endl;
            cout << setw(10) << "" << "The ASCII value of " << fourLetterWord[1] << " = " << int(fourLetterWord[1]) << endl;
            cout << setw(10) << "" << "The ASCII value of " << fourLetterWord[0] << " = " << int(fourLetterWord[0]) << endl;

            int sum = fourLetterWord[3] * pow(2, 24) + fourLetterWord[2] * pow(2, 16) +  fourLetterWord[1] * pow(2, 8) + fourLetterWord[0] * pow(2, 0);

            cout << setw(10) << "" << "If the four bytes of " << fourLetterWord << " were read as an int, its value would be " << sum << endl;
            cout << setw(10) << "" << "Let's reverse the process. " << endl;
            cout << setw(10) << "" << "Enter an unsigned int value: ";
            while(cin >> sum)
            {
                cout << setw(10) << "" << sum % int(fourLetterWord[3]) * pow(2, 24) + sum %     (fourLetterWord[2]) * pow(2, 16) 
                + sum % int(fourLetterWord[1]) * pow(2, 8) + sum % int(fourLetterWord[0]) * pow(2, 0);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << setw(10) << "" << "Please re-enter a four letter word.";
            cin >> fourLetterWord;
        }
    }
}
```

When I output this I get:

```
          Please enter a four letter word! FORE

          The ASCII value of E = 69
          The ASCII value of R = 82
          The ASCII value of O = 79
          The ASCII value of F = 70

          If the four bytes of FORE were read as an integer, its value would  be 1163022150
          Let's reverse the process. 
          Enter an unsigned integer value: 1163022150
          5.58767e+08
```

I need help getting my value 1163022150 to become the word FORE.

Comment: Don't use `pow(2, 24)` use `1 << 24`. The former is floating point, the latter is integral

Comment: Try casting each reversed number to a char ad see if that helps.

Comment: Please don't do `* pow(2, 24)`, instead read about bit shifts (eg `<< 24`). Incidentally the solution to your issue then becomes trivial as you can simply bit-shift back (`>> 24`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use bit shift operators to do the conversion both ways. You should not use `std::pow`. That may result in loss of accuracy.

```
int sum = (fourLetterWord[0] << 24) +
          (fourLetterWord[1] << 16) +
          (fourLetterWord[2] << 8) +
          fourLetterWord[3];   // No need for shifting this number.
```

Please note that I am bitshifting the first character in the string by 24, not the fourth character in the string.

You can extract the characters by bit masking and right shifting.

```
char digit1 = (sum & 0xFF000000) >> 24;
char digit2 = (sum & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
char digit3 = (sum & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
char digit4 = (sum & 0x000000FF); // No need for shifting this number.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can break it down similar to how you would decompose a decimal number into the 1s place, 10s place 100s place, etc.

To get the 1s place you would take the remainder when dividing by 10 (ie num % 10).

To get the 10s place you would first divide by 10, then repeat the same process: (num / 10) % 10 .

To get the 100s place you would first divide by 100, then repeat the same process: (num / 100) % 10 .

In your example, you are not using base 10, but rather base 2^8. Therefore, you will need to adjust 10 to be 2^8 and 100 (or 10*10) to be 2^16 (or 2^8*2^8), etc.

What you end up with is something like:

```
fourLetterWord[0] = sum          % 2^8;
fourLetterWord[1] = (sum / 2^8)  % 2^8;
fourLetterWord[2] = (sum / 2^16) % 2^8;
fourLetterWord[3] = (sum / 2^24) % 2^8;
```

Comment: Note that `^` is the bitwise XOR operator.  So `2^8` = `2 xor 8` = 10 (not 256). Likewise for `2^16` = `2 xor 16` = 18 (not 65536), and `2^24` = `2 xor 24` = 26 (not 16777216)

Comment: In C++, the `^` symbol is the bitwise-XOR operator, not the exponentiation operator. Also, because of signed integer division, dividing by these values is unlikely to properly preserve the data at each step, even if you do replace those constructs with the appropriate method to get those values. Please make sure to test your code and verify that it behaves the way you expect it to behave before you recommend it here.